# How to set window resolution in url

Tags: url, url-rewriting, screen-resolution, url-parameters, process.start

On button click, I have written a code to open application in another browser 
**`eg: Process.Start(firefox, url);`**

In the URL, I would like to pass window width and height parameter. 
Something like **`Process.Start(firefox, "http://www.google.com?window_height= "somthn "& window_width="somthn");`**

Is there any way to pass browser window width and height with URL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want, we can't do it directly, you need to find other way out.

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/294830/set-size-of-ie-process-window-c